# 副問い合わせのSELECT句につきましてご質問です

Tags: sql, oracle

以下の問題について、解説が理解できず困っています。

> 問) 平均給与が400を超える部署に所属する従業員を検索し、正しい記述について選択せよ。
>
> ```
> SELECT employee_name, salary, department_id FROM employees
> WHERE department_id IN
> 　(SELECT department_id, AVG(salary) FROM employees
> 　 GROUP BY department_id HAVING AVG(salary) > 400);
> ```
>
> 解答)
> 副問合せのSELECT句の列数が多いためエラーとなる。

解説では以下のような記載がありました。

> 副問合せで部署毎の平均給与が400を超える部署と平均給与を検索しており、複数の列を返す複数列副問合せになっています。
> しかし、主問合せのWHERE句でDEPARTMENT_ID列と副問合せの結果を比較していますが、副問合せのSELECT句の列数が多いためエラーとなります。

#### 質問

副問い合わせのSELECT句が、どの部分と比較して列数が多いのでしょうか。
参考サイトにあるように、WHERE句に指定された列のみ指定できるということなのでしょうか。

初歩的な質問で申し訳ございません。お手数ですがご教授お願いいたします。

参考サイト：
https://omachizura.com/2015/04/sql-subquery.html

Comment: 念のため問題と解説の出典 (URL等) を質問中に明記してください。

Comment: その通りだと思います。WHERE句に指定された列のみ指定できます。

Comment: サブクエリのSELECT avg(salary)が余計ですね。avg(salary)を削除すれば動くでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

> WHERE句に指定された列のみ指定できるということなのでしょうか。

違います。副問い合わせの結果(サブクエリのSELECTで選択する)列の「数」の問題です。

ごく単純化して言うと、IN でサブクエリを使用する場合、サブクエリのSELECTには1つの列しか指定できません。例では2つ指定されてるのでエラーになります。

参考サイトに記載されてるのは自己相関サブクエリの例なので、結果として「INの左辺」と「右辺のサブクエリのSELECTで指定する列」が同じになってるものになっていますが、一般論として考えれば、外側(親)のクエリに現れる列とサブクエリは独立してるものなので、「INの左辺」と「右辺のサブクエリのSELECTで指定する列」は一致しないのが普通です。

Answer (score 0):

以下、sqlite3では、
「INの左辺」と「右辺のサブクエリのSELECTで指定する列」の数が異なると、
エラーが発生するようです。
どうしても列数を同じにできない場合は、EXISTS句を利用するべきかと思っていました。
認識に誤りありましたら、教えていただけると助かります。

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # データの作成
    cursor.execute(sql='DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 果物テーブル;')
    cursor.execute(sql='CREATE TABLE 果物テーブル(id text, 名称 text);')
    cursor.execute(sql='INSERT INTO 果物テーブル(id, 名称) VALUES("A001", "りんご");')
    cursor.execute(sql='INSERT INTO 果物テーブル(id, 名称) VALUES("A002", "バナナ");')
    cursor.execute(sql='INSERT INTO 果物テーブル(id, 名称) VALUES("A003", "グレープ");')

    cursor.execute(sql='DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 価格テーブル;')
    cursor.execute(sql='CREATE TABLE 価格テーブル(id text, 価格 integer);')
    cursor.execute(sql='INSERT INTO 価格テーブル(id, 価格) VALUES("A001", "500");')
    cursor.execute(sql='INSERT INTO 価格テーブル(id, 価格) VALUES("A002", "600");')
    cursor.execute(sql='INSERT INTO 価格テーブル(id, 価格) VALUES("A003", "700");')

# データの検索
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    print('◇果物テーブル一覧表示')
    cursor.execute(sql='SELECT * FROM 果物テーブル;')
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(row[0], row[1])
    print('')

    print('◇価格テーブル一覧表示')
    cursor.execute(sql='SELECT * FROM 価格テーブル;')
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(row[0], row[1])
    print('')

    print('◇シンプルなIN句')
    cursor.execute(sql='SELECT * FROM 果物テーブル WHERE id IN("A001", "A003");')
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(row[0], row[1])
    print('')

    print('◇IN句で副問い合わせ')
    cursor.execute(sql='SELECT * FROM 果物テーブル WHERE id IN( SELECT id FROM 価格テーブル WHERE 価格>=600 );')
    # cursor.execute(sql='SELECT * FROM 果物テーブル WHERE id IN( SELECT * FROM 価格テーブル WHERE 価格>=600 );')
    # ↑副問い合わせのSELECT句に*を指定するとエラー「OperationalError: sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1」が発生しました。

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(row[0], row[1])
    print('')

    print('◇Existsで副問い合わせ')
    cursor.execute(sql='SELECT * FROM 果物テーブル WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM 価格テーブル WHERE 果物テーブル.id==価格テーブル.id AND 価格>=600 );')
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print(row[0], row[1])
    print('')
```

以下、実行結果です。

```
◇果物テーブル一覧表示
A001 りんご
A002 バナナ
A003 グレープ

◇価格テーブル一覧表示
A001 500
A002 600
A003 700

◇シンプルなIN句
A001 りんご
A003 グレープ

◇IN句で副問い合わせ
A002 バナナ
A003 グレープ

◇Existsで副問い合わせ
A002 バナナ
A003 グレープ
```

参考にしたサイト:https://www.sejuku.net/blog/73615

Answer (score 0):

副問合せで返ってくるデータセットをイメージすると良いと思います。
例題の副問合せデータセット(想像)

| department_id | AVG(salary) |
| --- | --- |
| aaaaa | 401 |
| bbbbb | 402 |
| ccccc | 403 |

主問合せのWHERE句にある条件である
`WHERE department_id IN(...)`で
department_idと一致するデータを見つける訳ですが
上記のデータセットの場合だと
`department_id`と`AVG(salary)`のどちらに一致したら結果を返せば良いか分からない訳です。
その為、一般的にはIN句を使用した副問合せの場合は下記のような**1列のみ**が返ってくるSQLを作る必要があります。

```
(SELECT department_id FROM employees
　 GROUP BY department_id HAVING AVG(salary) > 400)
```

| department_id |
| --- |
| aaaaa |
| bbbbb |
| ccccc |

または、department_idと一致することはほぼないので
実務上は意味のないデータとなりますが以下の副問合せでも構いません。

> 参考サイトにあるように、WHERE句に指定された列のみ指定できるということなのでしょうか。

これに対する回答としては違います。(※`AVG(salary)`でも良いため。)

```
(SELECT AVG(salary) FROM employees
　 GROUP BY department_id HAVING AVG(salary) > 400)
```

| AVG(salary) |
| --- |
| 401 |
| 402 |
| 403 |

Comment: `IN`の「定義」の問題なので、エラーの原因は「どちらに一致したら結果を返せば良いか分からない」という抽象的な話ではないです。例えば、検索対象が複数列であっても「1列目しか見ない」とか「複数列のいずれかと一致する」という「定義」であればそれが傍目にわかりにくかろうがエラーにはならないので。